# discord.py bot not sending chat logs to file properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I can't seem to make my discord.py bot send the chat logs of deleted messages to a text file correctly. It sends the logs, but it always replaces the old one instead of sending it to a new line.

```
import os
import discord
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    msg = str(message.author)+ ' - '+str(message.channel)+': '+str(message.content)
    with open('stats.txt', 'w') as f:
      print((msg), file=f)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: That's what `'w'` does, it truncates existing files. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must use `open('stats.txt', 'a')` and not `open('stats.txt', 'w')` because "w" overwrites the files, "a" writes afterwards (sorry for my English ^^)